# (py)zmq/PUB : Is it possible to call connect() then send() immediately and do not lose the message?

Tags: python, flask, zeromq, wsgi, pyzmq

With this code, I always lose the message :

```
def publish(frontend_url, message):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.connect(frontend_url)
    socket.send(message)
```

However, if I introduce a short sleep(), I can get the message :

```
def publish(frontend_url, message):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.connect(frontend_url)
    time.sleep(0.1)  # wait for the connection to be established 
    socket.send(message)
```

Is there a way to ensure the message will be delivered without sleeping between the calls to connect() and send() ?

I'm afraid I can't predict the sleep duration (network latencies, etc.)

**UPDATE:**

Context : I'd like to publish data updates from a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) REST application to a message broker (eg. on resource creation/update/deletion).

Currently, the message broker is drafted using the 0mq FORWARDER device

I understand 0mq is designed to abstract the TCP sockets and message passing complexities.

In a context where connections are long-lived, I could use it.
However, when running my Flask app in an app container like gunicorn or uwsgi, I have N worker processes and I can't expect the connection nor the process to be long-lived.

As I understand the issue, I should use a real message broker (like RabbitMQ) and use a synchronous client to publish the messages there.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this exactly, but there may be other solutions that would solve your problem.

Why are you using `PUB/SUB` sockets?  The nature of pub/sub is more suited to long-running sockets, and typically you will `bind()` on the `PUB` socket and connect on the `SUB` socket.  What you're doing here, spinning up a socket to send one message, presumably to a "server" of some sort, doesn't really fit the `PUB/SUB` paradigm very well.

If you instead choose some variation of `REQ` or `DEALER` to `REP` or `ROUTER`, then things might go smoother for you.  A `REQ` socket will hold a message until its pair is ready to receive it.  If you don't particularly care about the response from the "server", then you can just discard it.

Is there any particular reason you aren't just leaving the socket open, instead of building a whole new context and socket, and re-connecting each time you want to send a message?  I can think of some limited scenarios where this might be the preferred behavior, but generally it's a better idea to just leave the socket up.  If you wanted to stick with `PUB/SUB`, then just spin the socket up at the start of your app, sleep some safe period of time that covers any reasonable latency scenario, and then start sending your messages without worrying about re-connecting every time.  If you'll leave this socket up for long periods of time without any new messages you'll probably want to use heart-beating to make sure the connection stays open.

Comment: I use PUB sockets in this example because in the broker (see UPDATE), I use a SUB socket (publishers facing) and a PUB socket (subscribers facing). I agree I could (should?) use a PUSH socket on the Flask side and PULL socket on the broker side. And thanks for the suggestion about setting up the socket on the app start, I'll dot it.

Comment: Don't get stuck using certain socket types just because the metaphor makes sense to you. That seems to be the main reason people choose inappropriate socket types in their ZMQ apps. `PUSH/PULL` could work, I believe it has the same message delivery guarantee, that is, I don't think it'll discard a message if both ends aren't connected.

Answer (score 3):

From [the ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out):

> There is one more important thing to know about PUB-SUB sockets: you do not know precisely when a subscriber starts to get messages. Even if you start a subscriber, wait a while, and then start the publisher, the subscriber will always miss the first messages that the publisher sends. This is because as the subscriber connects to the publisher (something that takes a small but non-zero time), the publisher may already be sending messages out.

Answer (score -4):

Many posts here start with:

> "I used `.PUB/.SUB` and it did not the job I wanted it to do ... Anyone here, do help me make it work like I think it shall work out of the box."

This approach does not work in real world, the less in distributed systems design, the poorer in systems, where near-real-time scheduling and/or tight resources-management is simply un-avoid-able.

### Inter-process / inter-platform messaging is not "just another" simple-line-of-code (SLOC)

```
# A sample demo-code snippet          # Issues the demo-code has left to be resolved
#------------------------------------ #------------------------------------------------
def publish( frontend_url, message ): # what is a benefit of a per-call OneStopPUBLISH function?
    context = zmq.Context()           # .Context() has to be .Terminate()-d (!)
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)  # is this indeed "a disposable" for each call?
    socket.connect(frontend_url)      # what transport-class used for .connect()/.bind()?
    time.sleep(0.1)                   # wait for the connection to be established 
    socket.send(message)              # ^ has no control over low-level "connection" handshaking
```

Anybody may draft a few one-liners and put a decent effort ( own or community outsourced ) to make it finally work ( at least somehow ).

However this is a field of vast capabilities and as such requires a bit of reshaping one's mind to allow its potential to become unlocked and fully utilised.

Sketching a need for a good solution but with wrong grounds or mis-understood SLOC-s ( be it copy/paste-d or not ) typically does not yield anything reasonable for the near, the less for the farther future.

Messaging simply introduces a new paradigm -- a new Macro-COSMOS -- of building automation in wider scale - surprisingly, your (deterministic) code becomes a member of a more complex set of **Finite State Automata** ( FSA ), that - not so surprisingly, as we intend to do some "MESSAGING" - speak among each other.

For that, there needs to be some [*local-resource-management*], some "outer" [*transport*], some "formal behaviour model etiquette" ( not to shout one over another ) [*communication-primitive*].

This is typically in-built into ZeroMQ, nanomsg and other libraries.

### **However, there are two important things that remain hidden.**

- The micro-cosmos of how the things work internally ( many, if not all, attempts to tweak this, instead of making one's best to make proper use of it, are typically waste of time )
- The **macro-cosmos** of how to orchestrate a non-trivial herd of otherwise trivial elements [*communication-primitives*] into a ROBUST, SCALEABLE messaging ARCHITECTURE, that co-operates across process/localhost/network boundaries and that meets the overall design needs.

Failure to understand the distance between these two worlds typically causes a poor use of the greatest strengths we have received pre-cooked in the messaging libraries.

Simply the best thing to do is to forget the one-liner tweaking approaches. It is not productive.

Understanding the global view first, allows you to harness the powers that will work best for your good to meet your goals.

### Why it is so complex?

[image]

*( courtesy nanomsg.org )*

Any non-trivial system is complex. Both in TimeDOMAIN and in ResourcesDOMAIN. The more, if one strives to create a stable, smart, High-performance, Low-latency, transport-class-agnostic Universal Communication Framework.

The good news is, this has been already elaborated and in-built into the micro-cosmos architecture.

The bad news is, this does not solve your needs right from the box ( except a case of some really trivial ones ).

Here we come with the macro-COSMOS design.

It is your responsibility to design a higher-space algorithm, how to make many isolated FSA-primitives converse and find an agreement in accord with the evolving many-to-many conversation. Yes. The library gives you "just" primitive building blocks (very powerful, out of doubt). But it is your responsibility to make the "outer-space" work for your needs.

And this can and typically is complex.

Well, if that would be trivial, then it most probably would have been already included "inside" the library, wouldn't it?

### Where to go next?

Perhaps a best next step one may do is IMHO to make a step towards a bit more global view, which may and will sound complicated for the first few things one tries to code with ZeroMQ, but if you **at least jump to the page 265** of [Pieter Hintjens' book, Code Connected, Volume 1](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step there.

One can start to realise the way, how it is possible to start "programming" the macro-COSMOS of FSA-primitives, so as to form a higher-order-FSA-of-FSAs, that can and will solve all the ProblemDOMAIN specific issues.

First have an un-exposed view on the **Fig.60** *Republishing Updates* and **Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair* and try only after that to go back to the roots, elements and details.

Comment: Interesting reading, and I get that you spent time writing that. But _really_? that seem too offtopic as per OP's problem

Comment: Back to the subject: Original post asks for help in a situation, the .PUB/.SUB pattern simply _cannot_ solve in any attempt to apply JUST this pair of ZMQ-primitives. Forgive me to state a simple fact, that without having a broader insight, nobody is able to setup a good distributed inter-process messaging. IF one tries, THEN it looks exactly as many posts here -- asking others to help do one's job ( the very one to first understand the problem & tools, to be THEN ABLE to sketch an architecture that meets the distributed inter-process messaging requirements (top-down) & only THEN design a code