# Python Streamlit Application Sending Message Via ZMQ

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq, streamlit

Quite new to Streamlit but I am trying to create a dashboard that is able to send messages via ZMQ to my server application that acts as a subscriber.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt
import time
import zmq
class StreamLitManager(object):
    def __init__(self,log_file_path,zmq_port="88888"):
        self.log_file_path = log_file_path
        self.port = zmq_port
        self.context = None
        self.socket = None

    def InitConnections(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        self.socket.bind("tcp://*:" + str(self.port))

        # Send Message


        # Close it right after using, this doesn't work as it doesn't close/terminate
        # I tried self.context.close() too, same situation
        self.context.term()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    submitted1 = st.form_submit_button('Submit 1')
    
    if submitted1:
        sm = StrategyManager(user_input)
        sm.InitConnections()
```

So the idea is whenever the user presses that submit 1 button, I want to send a message. The problem I'm experiencing is `ZMQError: Address in use`. Based on my superficial understanding of streamlit is that whenever some parameter changes, the entire code gets re-ran. This doesn't seem to play well when I am constantly creating a new ZMQ publisher connection of each user click of submit. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better design pattern I should be doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PUB/SUB is not a good pattern here where it's constantly getting started & stopped as you will likely lose messages. See here for details [(py)zmq/PUB : Is it possible to call connect() then send() immediately and do not lose the message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085608/pyzmq-pub-is-it-possible-to-call-connect-then-send-immediately-and-do-no)